# How do i check for table data

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to check if table inside a sdf database is empty ?

```
if (table1 == "what here ?") { }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect to see SQL in there somewhere.  Here's how to get the number of rows in a relational database table:

```
SELECT count(*) from tableName
```

[Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/9da5cea2-1916-49e9-aa7f-4cf16e99ad9d/) a site that gives a LINQ example.